# Write bash function which operates on list of filenames

Tags: bash, scp, function, for

I want to define the function `cpfromserver` in bash so that when I run

```
$ cpfromserver xxx yyy zzz
```

the result is the same as if I had typed

```
$ scp user@remote.server:"/some/location/xxx/xxx.txt /some/location/xxx/xxx.pdf /some/location/yyy/yyy.txt /some/location/yyy/yyy.pdf /some/location/zzz/zzz.txt /some/location/zzz/zzz.pdf" /somewhere/else/
```

where it works for any number of arguments.

(That is, the function should copy `filename.txt` and `filename.pdf` from the directory `/some/location/filename/` on the `remote.server` to the local directory `/somewhere/else/` for every `filename` I specify as an argument to the function. And do it all in a single `ssh` connection.)

Currently, I have written a function that works for a single argument, and I just loop over it, but this establishes separate `ssh` connections for each argument, which is undesirable.

My difficulty is that I only know how to use function arguments individually by their position (`$1`, `$2`, etc.) — not how to manipulate the whole list.

[Note that I am writing this function as a convenience tool for my own use only, and so I would prioritize my own ease of understanding over handling pathological cases like filenames with quotation marks or linebreaks in them and whatnot. I know that the filenames I will be using this with are well-behaved.]

Comment: You can use `shift` operator with `$#` to get the last argument.

See more at [http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/shift]

Comment: Tangentially, you may want to look into the ssh ControlMaster option, which can be used to multiplex ssh connections.  This would remove much of the overhead of using one connection per file, and might make the whole problem moot.

Comment: @godlygeek No, the reason separate ssh connections for each file are undesirable is because the administrators of the remote server flagged my account for suspicious activity due to my exceeding 200 ssh connections in one day. The overhead wasn't bothering me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way:

```
cpfromserver () {
    files=''
    for x in "$@"
    do
        files="$files /some/location/$x/$x.txt /some/location/$x/$x.pdf"
    done
    scp user@remote.server:"$files" /somewhere/else/
}
```

*Important caveat from comments*: "It's worth noting for posterity that this solution definitely won't work for complicated filenames. If a filename contains a space, or a newline, or quotes, this approach will definitely fail."

Comment: You can skip the `in $@`. `for i` is a shortcut for `for i in $@`.

Comment: I had just finished typing in this exact answer, almost verbatim.  I used "arg" instead of "x" and "args" instead of "files", otherwise letter for letter the same.  Oh well, +1

Comment: @muru good to know.

Comment: @muru, I'd argue it's harder to read for newbs.  Just because you can be less verbose doesn't necessarily mean you should.

Comment: The `scp` command strikes me as weird. Does it really work that way?

Comment: It's worth noting for posterity that this solution definitely won't work for complicated filenames.  If a filename contains a space, or a newline, or quotes, this approach will definitely fail.

Comment: I don't think that is proper `scp` syntax. You can't do `user@host:"file list"` as far as I am aware. You need to repeat `user@host` for each file.

Comment: @muru, jw013, yes, it does work that way.  You can test it pretty trivially before downvoting...

Comment: @godlygeek I didn't downvote. Since apparently some amount of interpretation is done by a shell on the other side (`~`, `*`, etc. working indicates that), I suppose a space separated list of files is possible as long as filenames don't have spaces.

Comment: This answer works great for me. I edited in @godlygeek's warning about filenames into the bottom of the question to make sure others who come by this question will see it.

Comment: @jherran Is there a particular reason for the mixture of single quotes in line 2 with double quotes elsewhere?

Comment: @thecommexokid No reason, you can use double quotes on line 2 if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here a simple example:

```
#!/bin/bash

files_to_copy=''
destination_directory=''

while (("$#")) ; do
  if [[ "$@" = "$1" ]] ; then
    # last argument
    destination_directory="$1"
  else
    # argument
    files_to_copy="$files_to_copy $1"
  fi
  shift
done

scp user@remote.server:"$files_to_copy" $destination_directory;
```

If you run `./example.sh foo.pdf foo.txt foo.jpg backup/` you should get:

```
# this will be executed
scp user@remote.server:" foo.pdf foo.txt foo.jpg" backup/
```

Comment: This is overcomplicated because it solves a problem that the OP doesn't seem to have - passing the destination directory along with the source files. If you remove that extra logic, what you're left with is the same as jherran's solution.

Comment: @godlygeek agreed. Indeed I create a more flexible but also overcomplicated solution.

Answer (score -1):

The main idea is to prepare string with the list of files to operate (even through the loop) than transfer the string to command:

```
sloc='/some/location'
unset flist
for i in "$@"
do
    flist[${#flist[*]}]="$sloc/$i/$i".pdf
    flist[${#flist[*]}]="$sloc/$i/$i".txt
done
scp user@remote.server:"${flist[@]}" /somewhere/else/
```

Comment: "$[@]" should be "$@".  The expansion of "${flist[*]}" needs to be quoted to prevent additional word splitting - otherwise the wrong number of arguments are sent.

Comment: @godlygeek `${flist[*]}` should not be quoted as all elements is already quoted by `printf`

Comment: no.  scp is supposed to get called with two arguments, the first being "user@remote.server:/path/to/file1.pdf /path/to/file1.txt" and the second being "/somewhere/else".  I've tried your version, and at least with bash 3.2.25 it calls scp with 3 arguments, 1) user@remote.server:"/some/location/file1/file1.pdf" 2) "/some/location/file1/file1.txt" 3) /somewhere/else/

Comment: @godlygeek I would like to agree with [jw013](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/9537/jw013) and add `user@remote.server` for each argument of `scp`

Comment: That version would work, but it won't solve the OP's original problem: "Currently, I have written a function that works for a single argument, and I just loop over it, but this establishes separate ssh connections for each argument, which is undesirable."  Putting multiple "user@remote.server:file" arguments will create multiple ssh connections.